# Where should I store Logger code to reduce dependencies?

Tags: c#, oop, dependencies, log4net

I'm using Log4Net to handle logging in my WPF application.

Currently, the logger is configured with the rest of the front-end code. I have to pass a reference to the Service layer and the Repository layer if I want to be able to use the logger in these layers (I'll actually be using StructureMap for this). This means the back-end has a dependency on the front-end and I don't like that.

I'm wondering how best to handle this? Should I configure the logger in the Repository layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log4net [LogManager.GetLogger(string name)](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.LogManager.GetLogger_overload_1.html) will return an existing logger instance if it has already been created (e.g., in another layer), so there is no need to pass logger objects around.

You do need to be aware of multiple threads/processes trying to write to the same log file at the same time. You can use the log4net MinimalLock, or try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26579/Logging-into-single-file-from-multi-process) third party solution. Neither is ideal (the codeproject one is inefficient and still hits concurrency problems). I have ended up writing my own (which unfortunately is not publicly available).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following in my Service class: `ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("sdfsd")` and `ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("_logger")`. Both worked, but they're just random text (i.e. I'd expect them *not* to work). As such, what does `string name` refer to? What name should I be supplying or does it matter?

Comment: I have not checked the log4net code (which is available on the log4net web site), but I imagine there is an internal cache which is keyed on the name you supply. The documentation is a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

Logging is a common cross-cutting concern that I have seen handled in several different ways.  The simplest method is to create a static class that lives in a common assembly that is shared by all the layers.

However, since you are using StructureMap for your IoC, a better solution would be to configure StructureMap to inject your logger class (which might be configured as a singleton, depending on your needs) into each instance created.  I personally prefer property injection for such cross-cutting concern classes, so that constructors don't get cluttered, but that's a matter of preference.